# Mobile app: What text in load dialogs?

Tags: mobile, modal-windows

In a mobile app when a user logs in, there is a Title and Message field, and either or both can be hidden. Should text be displayed there or should those be hidden?

[image: Example]

Comment: What's wrong with a simple animated spinning bitmap image, without text?  (Usable in any language!)  I would think text to be appropriate if there could be an extended wait time. And then the text would specifically address why the delay, what to do after 30 seconds, etc...

Comment: What are you going to load specifically?

Answer (score 1):

Give them any information you can. If you can tell them whats coming up thats a plus. This way they can focus their mind on whats coming up and possibly start to think about it and get in the mindset to use whats about to load.

**You can use this to remind them what they are waiting for and to encourage them to actually wait for it.** Remember users have short attention spans and if they are in a 3g location with slow internet connections they may click on the app go somewhere else , check it that its loading again and totally forget why they even opened it and close it and leave. Where if they see something like loading a list of baby sitters in the area they will remember oh yes i need a sitter for the company ball lets make sure that loads. I forgot who but one office limits their network traffic to 3g speed on friday afternoon so they are apathetic to the 3g users in the world and so they design their sites to be friendly in low bandwidth areas.

Many web developers have the attitude of who cares about non javascript users, however they dont realize that until their javascript parses everyone is a non javascript user. Even if its something simple like your the map and your address book are loading they know that they can mentally be prepared for some sort of map and address book.

**In short I would put the title and text there for 2 reasons.**

1. Tell them whats coming next so they can mentally prepare for it and get their mindset in that context ahead of time.
2. Remind them of what they wanted to do so they dont close the app and forget to use it (likely to occur if loading times are extended).